# Reason of mismatch of projection system of rasterlayer and featurelayer?

Tags: arcobjects, coordinate-system

What I would like to check is if the raster layer and feature layer have the same projection.

Code developed so far:

```c#
public bool IsSpatialReferenceSame(ISpatialReference sp1, ISpatialReference sp2)
{
  return sp1.Equals(sp2);
}
```

In SpatialReference Class:

```c#
public bool Equals(ISpatialReference sp2)
{
  var sp1Clone = this.Clone;
  var sp2Clone = sp2.Clone;
  return sp1Clone.IsEqual(sp2Clone);
}
```

When I checked the feature layer and raster layer spatial reference in layer properties, I saw this.
Feature Layer Properties:
[image: Feature Layer Projection]
Raster Layer Properties:
[image: Raster Layer Projection]

But when I call IsSpatialReferenceSame it returns false.

Comment: It is solved. Horizontal projection parameters are same but vertical projection parameters are not same.

Comment: write the answer in the answer box and then approve it so this does shows as ab answered question.

Comment: Always remember that an ArcGIS `SpatialReference` is *not* the same as a coordinate system referenced by SRID. Yes, the (horizontal) coordinate system is a component, but so is the Vertical Coordinate System (VCS) and the false origins, precisions, and tolerances in the X, Y, Z, and M dimensions.  Rasters ignore the offsets and tolerances, but they remain properties of the object.

Comment: @Vince, Thank you for your comment. I was new in GIS when the question asked.

Comment: It's a good Question, and will have a good Answer when undeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, horizontal coordinate systems are same of projection system of the layers. But there is a mismatch of vertical coordinate systems of projection of the layers. For this reason, return false.

For checking the horizontal coordinate systems code developed

```c#
public bool IsHorizontalParamsSame(ISpatialReference sp2)
    {
        var thisParams = this.GetProjectionParameterValues();
        var sp2Params = sp2.GetProjectionParameterValues();

        var keys = thisParams.Keys.ToList().Union(sp2Params.Keys.ToList()).ToList();

        if (thisParams.Count != sp2Params.Count) return false;

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            if (!(sp2Params.ContainsKey(key) && thisParams.Keys.Contains(key))) return false;

            if (sp2Params[key] != thisParams[key]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetProjectionParameterValues()
    {
        var paramList = GetProjectionParameters(_spatialReference as IProjectedCoordinateSystem4GEN);

        return GetParamValueDictionary(paramList);
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetParamValueDictionary(IParameter[] parameters)
    {
        var paramValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            IParameter currentParameter = parameters[i];
            if (currentParameter != null)
            {
               paramValues.Add(currentParameter.Name.ToUpper(),currentParameter.Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        return paramValues;
    }
```

It returns true.

For checking vertical coordinate systems availability code developed:

```c#
public bool IsVerticalProjectionAvailable()
    {
        var sp = _spatialReference as ISpatialReference3;
        if ((_spatialReference is ISpatialReference3) && (sp.VerticalCoordinateSystem != null)) return true;

        return false;
    }
```

And for one it returns true and for another one returns false. This is the reason for mismatching spatial reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use the Interface [ICompareCoordinateSystems](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#icomparecoordinatesystems.htm).

I'm wondering if it is failing the test because one is named BTM and the other is Transverse_Mercator_complex.

Comment: Projection are same Transverse_Mercator_complex. Feature layer and raster layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try comparing the ISpatialReferenceInfo.Name property. This would essentially be a string comparison and would be much more straight forward.